# Giving condition to avoid error SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded.:

Tags: apex, governorlimits, singleemailmessage

I want to give the condition if already hit the email limitation in Salesforce then the email is not sent.
because right now I got the error First exception on row 0; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded.: and stop my other process

what I did right now is like this.
am I right? I should check apiRequestsLimit.getValue to check if email < 5000 and getEmailInvocations to check if email < 10.

really need your advice guys, thankyou

```
Map<String,System.OrgLimit> limitsMap = OrgLimits.getMap();
System.OrgLimit apiRequestsLimit = limitsMap.get('SingleEmail');
Integer used = apiRequestsLimit.getValue();
Integer emailLimit = apiRequestsLimit.getLimit();
        
Integer usedInvoc = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
Integer emailLimitInvoc = Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations();
if((used <= emailLimit) && (usedInvoc <= emailLimitInvoc) ){
    Messaging.sendEmail(listmail); //send email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to do the following

```
try {
  Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapicity(numberOfEmails);
}
catch (System.HandledException ex) {
  // decide what to do - e.g.delay email until next day
}
```

[Apex Reference Doc - Messaging Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_Messaging_reserveSingleEmailCapacity)